# Crash due to removal of Elements like CCSprite from NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, nsmutablearray, ccsprite, removechild

So, here's how it goes.

I am currently working on Cocos2d game, which consists of many Obstacles. One obstacle gets added on the screen at an interval of 10 seconds like this.

```
ObstacleSprite* newObstacle = [ObstacleSprite spriteWithFile:@"Obstacle.png" rect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20)];
            newObstacle.position = ccp(mainPlayer1.position.x,10);
[self addChild:newObstacle];

[self.arrayForObstacles addObject:newObstacle];
```

Now, I insert these obstacles into the `arrayForObstacles` because I also want to keep checking whether the Obstacles and MainPlayer don't collide.

I check it with the help of this function.

```
- (void) checkCollisionWithObstacle
{
    if(mainPlayer1.playerActive)
    {
        for(int  i = 0; i < [self.arrayForObstacles count]; i++)
        {
            ObstacleSprite* newObstacle = [self.arrayForObstacles objectAtIndex:i];
            if(newObstacle != nil)
            {
                if(CGRectIntersectsRect([mainPlayer1 boundingBox], [newObstacle boundingBox]))
                {
                    mainPlayer1.livesLeft--;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**THE ISSUE**

Problem is when I get to certain score, one of the Obstacles gets deleted. Removal of Obstacles works as in First In-First Out (FIFO) mode. So, to delete obstacles, I write the following method :

```
- (void) keepUpdatingScore
{
    //update new score
    mainPlayer1.score+=10;
    //remove obstacle when score increases by 5k
    if(mainPlayer1.score > 5000 && mainPlayer1.score > 0)
    {        
        mainPlayer1.playerActive = NO;

        if([self.arrayForObstacles count] > 0)
        {            
            CCLOG(@"count is %d",[self.arrayForObstacles count]);
            ObstacleSprite* newObstacle = [self.arrayForObstacles objectAtIndex:0];
            [self.arrayForObstacles removeObjectAtIndex:0];
            [self removeChild:newObstacle cleanup:YES];

            CCLOG(@"count is %d",[self.arrayForObstacles count]);
        }

        mainPlayer1.playerActive = YES;

    }    
    else
    {

    }
```

It crashes when score crosses 5000 mark!

**UPDATE**

Crash happens when it again goes to the method `checkCollisionWithObstacle`.

This is the THREAD Look.

[image]

THis is the line Which crashes.

[image]

Comment: what is the nature of the crash ? does the CCLOG get printed on the console ? (if not, your entire array could have been deallocated if you did not retain it.

Comment: I have a retain property given to the array. And I initialize the array like this   `self.arrayForObstacles = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:0];`

Comment: So what error do you get? EXC_BAD_ACCESS? Which line causes the crash,  `[self.arrayForObstacles removeObjectAtIndex:0];`?

Comment: It doesn't give any error type. and, after I set mainPlayer.playerActive = YES,  then it goes to `checkCollisionWithObstacle ` and crashes

Comment: Still not sure what actually happening, I need to know line (maybe it throws you to main.m) and error description(EXC_BAD_ACCESS or what?).

Comment: Its an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error, sorry I was just checking the logs and missed that xcode was showing an error in code. I have uploaded a screenshot.please check

Comment: OK, I don't see anything too bad in code you provided here which could cause this. You, probably, over released something or forgot to retain (or lost pointer if you use ARC). Check `[self removeChild:newObstacle cleanup:YES]` and consequences of `mainPlayer1.playerActive = YES`. 
P.S. ` if(mainPlayer1.score > 5000 && mainPlayer1.score > 0)` second expression is not required if n>5000, than n>0

Comment: Turns out, I have commented out the `[self.arrayForObstacles removeObjectAtIndex:0];` code, but it still crashes. I do not use ARC. Thanks for the logic change, it was left there as before it was `if(mainPlayer1.score % 5000 && mainPlayer1.score > 0)`

Comment: @MANIAK_dobrii please read the below answer and its comments if it could help you to help me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you seem to be using mainPlayer1.playerActive as a semaphore to block checking the checkCollisionWithObstacle loop from a delete in the keepUpdatingScore method (are they asynchronous ?). Assuming they are, the way you are blocking the loop access wont work if the code enters keepUpdatingScore AFTER the loop started in checkCollisionWithObstacle ... your mileage will vary.

Comment: Yes, they are asynchronous, and I think this might be the problem. Could you provide any solution to this? Btw, thanks a lot for providing atleast a reasoning to this!

Comment: This should be the problem. 'removeObjectAtIndex:0' would decrement all the objects' index from the array and hence no object would be found at the end. Hence, the crash :(